# Windows ReadFile/WriteFile guarantees with named pipes

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

I have a service/broker/inject setup all connected by named pipes.  The high integrity service runs in session 0 while it spawns low integrity broker processes into each session to communicate with injected DLLs within session processes.  It all works great.

```
                                   [Process 1]
                                 /
              [Broker Session 1] - [Process 2]
            /                    \
            |                      [Process N]
 [Service]  - [Broker Session 2] 
            |
            \
              [Broker Session N]
```

My question has to do with the synchronous Read/Write operations between components.

When you create a named pipe, you specify a buffer size.  If you write more than the specified size, if no buffer space is available then the `WriteFile` call will block until `ReadFile` is called to open up buffer space.  `ReadFile` will then return `FALSE` with `GetLastError` set to `ERROR_MORE_DATA` to indicate that more data is available to be read.

In my example above, multiple clients are writing data to the broker (each connection was spun off into its own thread) which then writes it to the service over a single pipe connection.  My question is, are `WriteFile` calls on the same handle serialized so that one has to complete before another can begin?

For example, let's say Process 1 and Process 2 both send data buffers to the session 1 broker and that each data buffer is larger than the pipe buffer size between the broker and service.  Process 1 calls `WriteFile` first on its thread and writes PIPE_BUFFER of data but then that thread is pre-empted by Process 2's thread which subsequently calls `WriteFile` and writes PIPE_BUFFER of data.  Meanwhile, the service's `ReadFile` is chugging along reading the buffers.  Is it guaranteed to read all of Process 1's data (because that is the first to initiate the `WriteFile`) or will it receive Process 1's first chunk (which causes ReadFile to return `FALSE` and `ERROR_MORE_DATA`) and then on the next call get Process 2's first chunk (again with a return value of `FALSE` and `ERROR_MORE_DATA`).  To put it in a rough diagram, can the service ReadFile return something like this?

```
|-------------| |-------------| |-------------| |-------------|
| Buffer1 1/2 | | Buffer2 1/2 | | Buffer1 2/2 | | Buffer2 2/2 |
|-------------| |-------------| |-------------| |-------------|
```

Or is it always guaranteed to return this:

```
|-------------| |-------------| |-------------| |-------------|
| Buffer1 1/2 | | Buffer1 2/2 | | Buffer2 1/2 | | Buffer2 2/2 |
|-------------| |-------------| |-------------| |-------------|
```

To maybe rephrase my question a bit, does the `WriteFile` API have any internal locking on the handle to prevent another call from initiating before a previous call had a chance to fully flush its buffer?  Obviously it does block but is that blocking just per-thread or *any* thread that tries to write to the handle?  Seems like it should, and I haven't observed an out of order read yet, but that doesn't necessarily mean much.

Comment: *are WriteFile calls on the same handle serialized* - on synchronous file object - yes. all (not only write) operation is serialized - new not begin until old not finished. but you not use the same file. each client process have own unique file object. but sure, that npfs of course serializing writes, especially in PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE case, which you use. messages can not mix.

Comment: Not a real problem.  As documented: "Therefore, if your specified buffer size is too small, the system will grow the buffer as needed, but the downside is that the operation will block".